# Disk size for Azure VM on docker-machine

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, docker-machine

I am creating an Azure VM using `docker-machine` as follows.

```
docker-machine create --driver azure --azure-size Standard_DS2_v2 --azure-subscription-id #### --azure-location southeastasia --azure-image canonical:UbuntuServer:14.04.2-LTS:latest --azure-open-port 80 AwesomeMachine
```

following the instructions [here](https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/azure/). Azure VM [docs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-sizes/) say - `Max. disk size` of `Standard_DS2_v2` is 100GB,

however when I login to the machine (or create a container on this machine), the max available disk size I see is 30GB.

```
$ docker-machine ssh AwesomeMachine
docker-user@tf:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        29G  6.9G   21G  25% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            3.4G   12K  3.4G   1% /dev
tmpfs           698M  452K  697M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            3.5G  1.1M  3.5G   1% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
none             64K     0   64K   0% /etc/network/interfaces.dynamic.d
/dev/sdb1        14G   35M   13G   1% /mnt
```

What is the meaning of `Max. disk size` then? Also what is this `/dev/sdb1`? Is it usable space?

Comment: How is this related to *docker* or *containers* in general? What kind of VM did you buy? `--azure-size` simply sets the `AZURE_SIZE` environment variable for a container. Setting it doesn't mean it will automagically grow a smaller VM to that size.

Comment: I removed the `docker` tag from the question. I don't think I bought any VM specifically. I have an azure subscription and I use that subscription to create VM (using the command mentioned in the question). I am not trying to increase size of any VM. I am trying to create a new VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, I didn't look at the documentation carefully.

Wo when `--azure-size` is `Standard_DS2_v2`, Local SSD disk = 14 GB, which is `/dev/sdb1`, while
`--azure-size Standard_D2_v2` gives you Local SSD disk = 100 GB.

Not deleting the question in case somebody else makes the same stupid mistake.